# How to state fractions with units of measurement? (e.g. 0.75 lb, 1.5 lbs, 1.75 lbs, etc.)

Tags: grammar, number, measure-word

"1 lb" is 一磅 and "half-pound" is 半磅. And "3/4" is 四分之三. So far, so good.

But I'm not clear on how to read measurements like 3/4 lb, 1.5 lbs and 1.75 lbs in Chinese. My guesses below would be:

- 3/4 lb = 四分之三磅
- 1.5 lbs = 一個半磅
- 1.75 lbs = 一個四分之三磅 (?) - This is the one I'm most confused about. I'm not totally sure how to string together all the elements

Also, I'm specifically using pounds as the unit of measurement here because I live in the US and I frequently need to state fractions of a pound, but I'd be curious if there are any relevant differences with other units of measurements, in particular grams and kilograms.

Comment: Written form - you might as well just keep the numbers as they are and add 磅 on the end: .75磅、1.5磅、1.75磅 here's some examples I found online: 女生练习1.75磅的哑铃胳膊上的肌肉会不会越来越大_百度知道 ||| 1.5磅(常衡制)等于多少公斤  ---- speaking: it would best to following biezhi's suggestions below - just treat them as numerals  ---- 斤 is one of the most common measurements you will encounter in China you can use 百度 http://dwz.cn/5pCVbc to get the different measurements

Answer (score 4):

在中文里他们正确的读法是下面这样：

- 3/4 lb = 四分之三磅
- 1.5 lbs = 一点五磅
- 1.75 lbs = 一点七五磅

Comment: 1.75 lbs ( one and three quarter pound) can also be written as 一又四分三磅. *if you have 又(and) in the number, you  can omit 之 in 四分之三*

Comment: 1.5 lbs can be written as 一磅半

Answer (score 4):

1.5 lbs = 一磅半 (only when 'and a half') or 一點五磅

1.75 lbs = 一**又**四分之三磅 or 一點七五磅

Since 個 is actually a unit itself, there should not be 個 when there are units and should also be used after the number such as 一**又**四分之三個.

What's more, if not with half, smaller units are preferred. e.g. `1.75 lbs` -> `1 lb 12 oz`(一磅十二盎司).

Comment: No body uses imperial units in PRC so I guess no one will convert 1.75 lbs to ounces.

Comment: @LuciusHu I just used a bad example. It should be better to make examples with traditional units like _Jin_, _Liang_ and _Qian_.

Comment: Good point, that's more often used.